# Are there any benefits to use Websockets instead of raw TCP sockets in LAN?

Tags: tcp, websocket

Assuming there is a client-server application running in a LAN. Clients are WPF applications and the server is a Windows service.  Are there any benefits to use Websockets instead of raw TCP sockets for client-server communication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The primary benefit of WebSockets in general is that they are available in web browsers. If your application is not running in a web browser, there is no point in using WebSockets.